# How to make a column layout in grommet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jsx, grommet

I'm using Grommet React library for ux. I'm working on a phone layout project.

I've a prop from redux state that represent an array of element. The initial state is empty array and, after server returning, the props will be

```
[{ country: 'England' }, { country: 'Germany' }, { country: 'Spain' }, { country: 'Zimbawe' }]
```

What I want is a column layout with exactly two columns by row where each column get 50% of available space.

To do so I've used the Column component in this way

```
<Columns responsive={false}>
    {this.props.countries.map(this.renderCountries)}
</Columns>
```

And finally the renderCountries method

```
renderCountries (country) {
    return <Box key={country.country}>{country.country}</Box>
}
```

But with this code the system will render only one element by row. How can I get two columns by row?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to [Grommet Docs for Columns](https://grommet.github.io/docs/columns/examples?size=large&justify=center&maxCount=2) layout is going to be calculated by the component itself.

What you can do is to set props for `Columns` and `Box` to achieve desired layout is, you can give `size` prop for `Columns` and `Box` and combine it with the `maxCount` prop.

> **maxCount**    *number*
>
> Number of columns to allow for masonry option,
>   based on component width. Responds based on the width of the column
>   children (set with size).
>
> **size**        *small|medium|large*
>
> The width of each column. Defaults to
>   medium.

**For Example**

Below example will assure you would have maximum 2 columns if the device/window/parent width is enough to fit in. Otherwise its gonna show 1 column.

```
<Columns maxCount={2} size="large" responsive={false}>
    {this.props.countries.map(this.renderCountries)}
</Columns>

renderCountries (country) {
    return <Box key={country.country}>{country.country}</Box>
}
```

Other than these props you can also play with `Box` component props to achieve desired layout.

Comment: The propblem is with min number of columns. Because I work on mobile the Column component show always only one column per row. So your answer not help me at all.

Comment: Did you tried to set size of the boxes like shown in the docs?

Comment: Yes. Columns width will reduce but remains one per row. If I set masonry={true} than I got an error when data is empty array

Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined

Comment: Did you try to set `basis` of boxes to `1/2` and making them half width?